# Global UINavigationBar instance

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

Inside my AppDelegate I want to access to the global UINavigationBar instance, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if it's 'global' then i assume you are adding it programmatically from the appdelegate. If you are then just assign it to an appdelegate instance variable set to retain. If it's not created in the appdelegate then still use an instance variable like I said but to set it, when you create the `UINavigationController` then set it by using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

to access your app delegate instance and then set your navigation controller variable on it. Hope this helps.